# Set column breakpoints using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to develop a grid of cards using rows and columns.
Since I started using bootstrap, I always had doubts about how to use the column breakpoints correctly. I intend that in desktop size, it will have three columns, but in mobile size, these three columns will "become" just one.

Does anyone know how I can configure breakpoints in order to get just everything in one column, in mobile size?

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgt2mu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        dayly
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                This is some text within a card body.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                This is some text within a card body.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        This is some text within a card body.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        This is some text within a card body.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        This is some text within a card body.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        This is some text within a card body.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                This is some text within a card body.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                This is some text within a card body.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                This is some text within a card body.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                This is some text within a card body.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        dayly
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row" style="height:50%">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        dayly
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:calc(50% - 16px); margin-top:16px">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        dayly
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row" style="height:25%">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        dayly
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:calc(75% - 16px); margin-top:16px">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        dayly
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

[image: Imagem]

I set the moblie size and get 3 columns, how can I get everything in just one column and occupying the entire screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use `col-sm` on the columns...

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> dayly </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                                <div class="card-body"> This is some text within a card body. </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                                <div class="card-body"> This is some text within a card body. </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> This is some text within a card body. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> This is some text within a card body. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> This is some text within a card body. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> This is some text within a card body. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body"> a </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body"> s </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body"> s </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body"> Ta </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 16px;">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> dayly </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="row" style="height:50%">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> dayly </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height:calc(50% - 16px); margin-top:16px">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> dayly </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="row" style="height:25%">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> dayly </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height:calc(75% - 16px); margin-top:16px">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
                        <div class="card-body"> dayly </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/DPFuoonZgF

Also, you can use the padding utils (ie: `pb-3`) on some of the columns to create vertical spacing on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

This is 1 column on mobile & 3 columns otherwise, based on a 12 column grid.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">...</div>
```

The instruction is - fill all 12 columns by default (mobile first), and fill 4 of the columns otherwise.

I think your issue may come from nesting cols within cols, so for simplicity I've reduced this to just one level deep:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Card 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Card 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Card 3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/oNjWmqm).

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to apply but I still get the 3 columns. I've read several articles and still don't understand how to implement this perfectly

Comment: Ok, let me update my answer with a codepen to demonstrate

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I use several col to build the grid and not all work with it. I updated the post link. Can you help me?